# How to remove db initialization and connection step/code from JHipster microservice app?

Tags: jhipster

I have created java microservices app using JHipster with options jwt, mysqldb, elastic search etc.., I want to remove db related stuff. I just want to use this searvice for indexing user given data to elastic search and apply search on it.

I'm new to java and so need help to remove db related stuff from this kind of app. Please help

Comment: Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to edit `.yo-rc.json` file from your project, and change `"databaseType": "sql"` to `"databaseType": "no"` and re-generate your app using `yo jhipster` but there's no guarantee that it will work as "no db + ElasticSearch" is probably not a supported use case.
You may have also to remove  "devDatabaseType" and "prodDatabaseType".

To be safer, you should rather copy your modified `.yo-rc.json` file to an empty directory and run `yo jhipster` from there.

Comment: Thank you. Not a direct solution but the best approach to solve this problem.